# Como colocar Checkbox de múltipla seleção em cada imagem

Tags: css

primeiro quero dizer que sou iniciante, criei esse CheckBox com muito esforço, e estou tentando colocar essas duas opções para cada imagem, ou seja cada imagem vai ter os 2 CheckBox para escolher a cor, porém so consegui colocar os 2 Checkbox na primeira imagem, nas outras eles se repetem, ja tentei colocar dentro do img, tentei criar uma div, não consegui, agradeço se poderem me mostrar o erro.

https://codepen.io/lucassilva322d/pen/XWzBJOy

```css
*{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.contador{
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-bottom: -20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}






.container {
  display: inline-flex;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  padding-left: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 22px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Hide the browser's default checkbox */
.container input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
}

/* Create a custom checkbox */
.checkmark {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: #eee;
}

/* On mouse-over, add a grey background color */
.container:hover input ~ .checkmark {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* When the checkbox is checked, add a blue background */
.container input:checked ~ .checkmark {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

/* Create the checkmark/indicator (hidden when not checked) */
.checkmark:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

/* Show the checkmark when checked */
.container input:checked ~ .checkmark:after {
  display: block;
}

/* Style the checkmark/indicator */
.container .checkmark:after {
  left: 9px;
  top: 5px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 10px;
  border: solid white;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
  







.containergrande{
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 550px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black;
  padding: 70px 10px;
}



.containergrande .top{
  width: 100%;
}

.containergrande .top img{
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
}

.containergrande .bottom{
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.containergrande .bottom label{
  width: 15%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.containergrande .bottom label img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#image-1:checked ~ .containergrande .top .image-1{
  display: block;
}

#image-2:checked ~ .containergrande .top .image-2{
  display: block;
}

#image-3:checked ~ .containergrande .top .image-3{
  display: block;
}

#image-4:checked ~ .containergrande .top .image-4{
  display: block;
}

#image-5:checked ~ .containergrande .top .image-5{
  display: block;
}

#image-6:checked ~ .containergrande .top .image-6{
  display: block;
}


input{
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}

@media (max-width: 576px){
  .containergrande{
    width: 90%;
  }
  .containergrande h1{
    font-size: 7vw;
  }
}
```

```html
    <input type="radio" name = "radio" id = "image-1" checked>
<input type="radio" name = "radio" id = "image-2">
<input type="radio" name = "radio" id = "image-3">
<input type="radio" name = "radio" id = "image-4">
<input type="radio" name = "radio" id = "image-5">
<input type="radio" name = "radio" id = "image-6">
<div class="containergrande">
  <div class="top">
    
    <div class="contador">
     19 Imagem selecionada
    </div>

    <label class="container">ROXO
      <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
      <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
    <label class="container">AZUL
      <input type="checkbox">
      <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
    
    </label>
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/IcNH8Mv.jpg" class = "image-1" alt="" >
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/q899Xtp.jpg" class = "image-2" alt="">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/aZFNqlJ.jpg" class = "image-3" alt="">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/q0Sq5Ay.jpg" class = "image-4" alt="">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/px46Bb4.jpg" class = "image-5" alt="">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/nGaKDRN.jpg" class = "image-6" alt="">
    
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    <label for="image-1"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/IcNH8Mv.jpg" alt=""></label>
    <label for="image-2"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/q899Xtp.jpg" alt=""></label>
    <label for="image-3"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/aZFNqlJ.jpg" alt=""></label>
    <label for="image-4"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/q0Sq5Ay.jpg" alt=""></label>
    <label for="image-5"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/px46Bb4.jpg" alt=""></label>
    <label for="image-6"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/nGaKDRN.jpg" alt=""></label>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score -1):

Tens que repetir as checkboxes, dar uma classe, escondê-las e usar o atributo checked das imagens para mostrar as checkboxes de cada imagem.

HTML:

```
    <div class="checkboxes-1">
      <label class="container">ROXO
        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
      </label>
      <label class="container">AZUL
        <input type="checkbox">
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
      </label>
    </div>
    
    <div class="checkboxes-2">
      <label class="container">ROXO
        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
      </label>
      <label class="container">AZUL
        <input type="checkbox">
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
      </label>
    </div>
    
    <div class="checkboxes-3">
      <label class="container">ROXO
        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
      </label>
      <label class="container">AZUL
        <input type="checkbox">
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
      </label>
    </div>
    
    <div class="checkboxes-4">
      <label class="container">ROXO
        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
      </label>
      <label class="container">AZUL
        <input type="checkbox">
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
      </label>
    </div>
    
    <div class="checkboxes-5">
      <label class="container">ROXO
        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
      </label>
      <label class="container">AZUL
        <input type="checkbox">
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
      </label>
    </div>
    
    <div class="checkboxes-6">
      <label class="container">ROXO
        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
      </label>
      <label class="container">AZUL
        <input type="checkbox">
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
      </label>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.checkboxes-1,
.checkboxes-2,
.checkboxes-3,
.checkboxes-4,
.checkboxes-5, 
.checkboxes-6 {
  display: none;
}

#image-1:checked ~ .containergrande .top .checkboxes-1{
  display: block;
}

#image-2:checked ~ .containergrande .top .checkboxes-2{
  display: block;
}

#image-3:checked ~ .containergrande .top .checkboxes-3{
  display: block;
}

#image-4:checked ~ .containergrande .top .checkboxes-4{
  display: block;
}

#image-5:checked ~ .containergrande .top .checkboxes-5{
  display: block;
}

#image-6:checked ~ .containergrande .top .checkboxes-6{
  display: block;
}
```